# I'm moving to Germany but want to keep my UK job. Any advice?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, relocation

I'm moving to Germany in September this year and I would like to keep my UK job (working completely remote).

The company I work for is all for this and is currently looking into it themselves too.
They've also offered to hire me as a contractor if we can't find another solution.

I'll be moving to Germany for about 2 years, but I wouldn't be able to pass of as temporary and so therefore liable to pay German tax.

I'll apply for residency as soon as I move but I'll also be keeping an address in the UK and a UK bank account too. I am also classified as a British citizen and do not plan to change this.

Has anyone had any experience with this? The situation with leaving the EU has made this quite a bit complicated. Cheers

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: As a UK citizen you must apply (and fulfill the conditions) for a residence permit. You do **not** need a visa beforehand (see point 5c of link). [Brexit information and FAQ - Federal Foreign Office: 5c](https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/information-on-brexit/brexit-information-faq?openAccordionId=item-2425346-2-panel) For remote working, this may be tricky due to taxes and health insurance. Your company should find a way to pay you directly in Germany, as an employee, that would make the fullfillment for the residence permit easier.

Comment: Brexit may make it very difficult for you to get a residence permit for Germany, but does it have any relevance for your other issues like taxation? I believe not. Had UK still been in the EU, you would still have been subject to income taxes in Germany. You will also need a German health insurance.

Comment: You will need to find a way to be in compliance with all the relevant tax and social security regulations as a German resident. In practice the best way to solve this is for you to be hired by a German entity. Either a subsidiary of your employer, or an agency that then just bills your employer.